# How to add google map on navigation drawer activity?

Tags: java, android, navigation, maps

Problem with this, This code is also not working..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener


mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);


    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                    .title("San Francisco")
                    .snippet("Population: 776733"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show your full activity class and layout xml file.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/149vo   here's my MainActivity File

Comment: here's my MainActivity XML file https://justpaste.it/149vr

Comment: content main XML file https://justpaste.it/149vs

Comment: I've added an answer, You may have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two processes. You have to change either in your xml or activity class code:

1) Either replace your map fragment in content_main.xml with the MapView (As Below):

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

2) Or replace this:

```
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco")
                .snippet("Population: 776733"));
    }
});
```

With:

```
 ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

       googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
           .title("San Francisco")
           .snippet("Population: 776733"));
   }

}
```

In your MainActivity class.

In your existing code, You have added a map fragment to the layout but calling for a mapview from activity. That's why it is not working.

To get API key, go [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) and **Generate** a key.

Copy the key and paste it in manifest under application tag:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Now the google map will show up.

Comment: This code works but when launching application it's just display google logo at bottom left corner and no map display. what will i do?

Comment: @Chandan Kumar, map is not showing cause you haven't added the api key. I've added the procedureof how to add api key to my answer please check.

Comment: check your error log if you are getting "Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure."

Comment: Error Log  - Authorization failure.  Please see 
03-09 12:10:59.317 3165-3245/com.finalproject.mapapp E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                 API Key: AIzaSyAsuyiU6dNMiE6IDmXWP9aClnMG12R_6v4

Comment: Does your API Key: AIzaSyAsuyiU6dNMiE6IDmXWP9aClnMG12R_6v4 match with the API key of console ? If yes, uninstall the app, clean build and re-run the app. If that also doesn't work generate a fresh API key and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution today.

1. Implement `OnMapReadyCallback` to `MainActivity`.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
        OnMapReadyCallback
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Implement `onMapReady()`. Keep it empty.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
   {
   }
   ```
3. In `onCreate()` method:

   ```
   SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
first you have to create the relative_layout because we can't add anything in map fragment so we add image button and map fragment in relative_layout.




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

here your drawer_layout

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

in MapActivity add implements method navigationView and then add this code below the getSupportedFragment

```
` DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);`
```

then write the onclick method on Imagebutton method which is `  public void

```
drawerclick(View view) {


            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
    enter code here

            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        }`
```